# Union or Minus rows based on 2 columns Pyspark Sql

Tags: sql, pyspark, hiveql

I have two result sets.

Table A looks like this:

```
Emp   ID1   ID2
Rios  123   324
```

Table B looks like this:

```
Emp   ID1   ID2
Rios  123   324
Rios  no_1  no_2
Stone no_1  no_2
```

I want my result set to look like this:

```
    Emp   ID1   ID2
    Rios  123   324
    Stone no_1  no_2
```

I was thinking a type of union or minus might work. Then I tried a right join where ID1 and ID2 not equal 'no_1' and 'no_2', respectively. But then I have all these extra columns, and ideally I want them stacked. I'm also using spark sql context so I'm not sure if I have other options. I've typically used sql workbench.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . Is this what you want?

```
select a.*
from a
union all
select b.*
from b
where not exists (select 1 from a where a.emp = b.emp);
```

Actually, your logic is a bit unclear.  This might also be what you want:

```
select b.*
from b left join
     a
     on a.emp = b.emp and a.id1 = b.id1 and a.id2 = b.id2
where a.emp = b.emp or a.emp is null;
```